# Objects Randomly Disappear

Tags: modeling, objects

This isn't the first time that this has happened to me. This also happened to a different project I had 2 months ago in version 2.8.

Objects would just disappear the next time I open the project. Yes I checked if they were in a hidden collection, I kept toggling / , and I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> . The first picture was a test render I made, and the second is what it is now from the same view.

[image]
[image]

There is no way that I accidentally deleted them, since staircase is made of 3 separate objects and I would have to select all of them at once then delete them. Besides that, other objects in different locations also disappeared at the same time.

The one thing I noticed is that the objects disappear after open and start working on a different project. There is no particular order that they disappear either. Below is a couch that I modeled. The main cushion was the first one that I made, followed by the 4 large pillows, then five smaller ones (The three in the middle and two on each side that were leaning on the arm rests). Even though I made the cushion first and the small pillows last, they both disappeared, along with a table I modeled many weeks before the couch itself.

[image]

I need help to somehow find out how to recover the objects and/or prevent this from happening again.

edit: screenshots of my outliner

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show a screenshot of your outliner

Comment: Check Orphan Data in your outliner, although I'm not sure how it would get there...

Comment: Is there any chance you have assigned another mesh to an object,  orphaning the original, wihich will be lost on reopening.   Eg shift D default cube. Assign mesh "Cube" to duplicate. "Cube.001" mesh will be orphaned.

Comment: I did use shift d to duplicate (the pillows for example, and the top boards on the stairs but in edit mode). But I don't know how to assign a mesh to another object so I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Try to press the <kbd>1</kbd> button on your keyboard (not on numpad) in *object mode*. You are maybe viewing different layer. This happened to me a few times.

Comment: Forgot to add it, but yeah I already made sure all layers and collections are active. This is the second time that happened to me on 2 different projects.